# Where does JavaScript sit in the MVC pattern of a web application?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm still confused about where JavaScript code sits in the MVC pattern when building a web application. I thought it worked like this.

- The Model is the database and the
  classes required to get the data
  in/out.
- The Controller would be the Classes where I write my logic
  that is, Java servlets, which accept an
  Ajax request and then make a call to
  the database;
- The View is the JSP page which is
  returned to the Ajax request via the
  servlet (my Controller)

Because JavaScript code is compiled in the browser I think of it as part of the View, but it's handling user inputs, making server requests based on those events and then returning the data to page, so would that also make in part of the Controller?

Also, what does it mean when they refer to the Domain Model in MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is going to be primarily a UI related concern; your view is making an ajax request to the controller. The controller isnt making an ajax request; nor is the model. For all intents and purposes, an ajax request isnt anything different than a normal request; it's just that the browser isnt hanging until your response is returned.

JavaScript also executes in the context of your client, outside the purview of your server, so it should go into the view.

Answer (score 3):

MVC is just a pattern.  JavaScript code itself can implement this pattern, so I don't think of it as fitting into some other portion of your server side framework's pattern.  Check out [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) for a good example of using MVC in JavaScript code.

You can model your JavaScript code off of similar concepts that you model your server side code with.  The JavaScript code itself will get served up through the view of your server side application, but unless you're only adding eye candy with JavaScript code (which you're not) then the JavaScript code is really its own entity and doesn't necessarily fit into your server side MVC paradigm.

Try to separate the JavaScript code from anything server side.  Just consider it an 'add on' that, if disabled in the browser, won't break your application from running.  I just add some niceties to allow for better interaction, etc.  How you actually model the JavaScript code is up to you, (but I do highly recommend Backbone)

One could also do a Rich frontend in javascript backed only by a data source.  In this case, once again, javascript will be responsible for maintaining models, views and controllers.

Domain model generally just refers to the business logic of your application.  The brains so to speak of what should actually happen in your app.  It's kind of an abstract concept encapsulating all the business logic of an app.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you recommend backbone.js and not something else for implementing the MVC pattern? ([PureMVC](http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_JS), [JavascriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/), etc)

Comment: never worked with pure, but javascript MVC, at least the last time I looked at it seemed far too bloated for what i've ever needed.  backbone is a very clean, simple implementation, the source is easy to follow and it clocks in at a pretty low file size.  I've also just found that it's inheritance pattern is great, making it nice for just straight up OO in javascript, even if you don't use any of the view/controller stuff as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, my personal experience in MVC, working with [Zend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) or [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), I think JavaScript code would be considered as a part of the View since JavaScript code is helping View and is directly interacting with the view. 
Send and receive of data through Ajax can be considered as a request.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript code is part of the View. The view is what gets output to the browser, and while Javascript code doesn't automatically have a visual appearance to it, it can be used to modify the DOM.

When you start talking about Ajax, it's easy to see JavaScript code as something else in the normal flow of things, but you should break down the process of an Ajax request to see it's just another HTTP request.

Some people will have a controller for just Ajax requests, while others may pass an  argument to a controller depicting an Ajax request to modify the output.

Either way, JavaScript code sits in the View and you may need to learn some other design strategies regarding Ajax in an MVC setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScript to work with the DOM so yes, it is part of the View. But you can still use JavaScript on the server side, in this case it could be part of the code related to the business.